# Why is the filesystem larger than logical volume?

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm, tmpfs

On the machine, there is a logical volume /dev/lvm/tmp of size 500MiB with the same size partition /dev/mapper/tmp that is mounted on /tmp.

Checking the logical volume:

```
# lvdisplay /dev/lvm/tmp
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/lvm/tmp
  LV Name                tmp
  VG Name                lvm
  LV UUID                R1a6Yq-b5jt-Y5rF-sCma-50yh-rg19-LB21qs
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time anarchy, 2021-04-01 13:28:12 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                500.00 MiB
  Current LE             125
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:0
```

However, checking the size of /tmp shows the size is 7.8G:

```
# df -h /tmp
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/tmp  7.8G   34M  7.8G   1% /tmp
```

Relevant line in /etc/crypttab:

```
tmp        /dev/lvm/tmp        /dev/urandom tmp,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256
```

Relevant line in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/tmp        /tmp        tmpfs   defaults       0 0
```

Additional info:

```
# cryptsetup status tmp
/dev/mapper/tmp is active.
  type:    PLAIN
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 256 bits
  key location: dm-crypt
  device:  /dev/mapper/lvm-tmp
  sector size:  512
  offset:  0 sectors
  size:    1024000 sectors
  mode:    read/write
```

Why is the size of /tmp 7.8G and not 500M?

Comment: Probably because `/tmp` is still mounted with a tmpfs ("double mounted" or your "crypt tmp" failed to mount, idk). Check with `findmnt /tmp` or so.

Comment: This is the output to findmnt /tmp:   /tmp /dev/mapper/tmp tmpfs  rw,relatime,inode64 
   Does that mean I need to remove the line in fstab?

Comment: It really depends on what you want. If you do not want to make use of your RAM for `/tmp`, then you should probably mask (or "edit", in the systemctl / overriding snippet sense) the tmp.mount unit (assuming systemd here).

Comment: Actually masking might prevent `/tmp` from being mounted with anything at all. To be frank I've never thought about what's the right thing to do if you don't want the default tmp.mount. (But I suppose "edit" will work anyway, just not sure if it's the best way.)

Comment: And now I wonder if it's actually a bug / flaw that needs to be fixed. It actually look surprising now that the tmp.mount generated from the fstab entry didn't simply override the default one. Maybe instead of "edit", having a overriding tmp.mount in /etc/systemd/system (and enable it) might be a cleaner way. (Hopefully it works better than the fstab entry approach.)

Comment: Yes, it does seem odd that status tmp.mount shows that it is generated from fstab, yet the size indicates RAM is being used. I'm considering scraping the tmp partition for now.

Comment: I believe the issue lies in mounting /dev/mapper/tmp with the file type tmpfs in fstab. Formatting and specifying another type (ext4, xfs) should be right.